# Trying to switch the security off for one URL with XML configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I checked several blogs / doc / stackoverflow forum entries but I still don't know what I am doing wrong.
I want to give access to an URL to anybody. The **`permitAll`** doesn't work as I have custom filters. So I thought to create a separate **`http`** element and use the **`security="none"`** setting but no success so far.

```xml
<security:http pattern="/status" security="none"/>

<!-- ******************** rules with encryption and HMAC authentication ******************** -->
<security:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" pattern="/**">
    <!-- HMAC only -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/logheaderpattern/check" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/approve" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/approve_and_forced_start" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/maintenancewindow/next/**" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/start/manual" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/start/eventlife" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/skip/eventlife" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/start/scheduled" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/cron/nextrun" access="authenticated" />
    <!-- HMAC and encryption (set in encryptionFilter) -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/worker/command/**" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/worker/event" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/worker/system/**" access="authenticated" />
    <!-- deny all others -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="encryptionFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="hmacAuthenticationFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
</security:http>


<!-- ******************** Defining the authentication manager ******************** -->
<security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false" id="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="fileBasedUserDetailsService">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And the controller:

```java
@Controller
public class WebController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String redirect() {
     return "redirect:/pages/status.html";
  }
}
```

And the Spring Boot initializer

```java
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml", "classpath:securityContext.xml"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.reaction.engine.controller", 
                            "org.reaction.engine.persistence.service",
                            "org.reaction.engine.persistence.converter",
                            "org.reaction.engine.service",
                            "org.reaction.engine.scheduling.utils"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
     return application.sources(WebInitializer.class);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     SpringApplication.run(WebInitializer.class, args);
  }

}
```

I keep getting the

```
  2018-01-15 16:04:02.676 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter:176] - Forwarding to error page from request [/status] due to exception [An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext]
  org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
          at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379)
          at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223)
          at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
          at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
```

exception. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried something like this:  <intercept-url pattern="/status*" access="permitAll" />

Comment: Hi @Airborne , I don't think I can use the `<intercept-url pattern="/status*" access="permitAll" />` as I have custom filters which I don't want to work for this specific URL.

Comment: No, I use only those 2 custom filters in securityContext.xml

Comment: ok, I see, that can explain it! If you add this comment as an answer I am more than happy to accept it. Thank you very much for your help! I think I am going to specify explicitly to my custom filter that this URL should be ignored and add a permitAll rule. thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It s a bug/missing feature in Spring Boot/Spring Security, see

- [Security filters in xml are automatically registered out of the FilterChainProxy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1594)
- [SEC-2723: Add meta-data to bean definitions of Spring Security Filter beans identifying them as "inner"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2948)

Some work-arounds are possible, one is to use Java configuration instead of XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
```

will not allow access to any resource irrespective of what ever sub pattern you define for other resources.

Change your pattern to somthing like

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="denyAll" /> /*add an extra folder and shift the resources there */
```

and

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />
```

Comment: Hi @globetrotter, I have a custom filter (for authorization) and I want to avoid to use it as it will refuse the request (401). Is there any way to disable the security for this URL? the `<security:http pattern="/status" security="none"/>` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Try this one because you are using filter..<security:http pattern="/status" filters="none"/> And if this doesnt work the pls share your filter code.

Comment: <security:http pattern="/status" security="none"/> <security:http pattern="/status" filters="none"/> you will have to use both.

Comment: the `filters="none"` is not supported in Spring Security anymore and my application throws an exception if I use it. My custom filter is to check HMAC authentication. I wouldn't want to change it as it works correctly and all I need to change my Spring Security config. I am kind of surprised that this easy task cannot be done...?